# JavaScript date validation for HTML

Tags: javascript, html

I am currently trying to create a form on a website, where a person fills in a date before submitting the form. If the user inputs a date before today, it will not submit the form and give an alert stating `"Date cannot be before today"`.

However, I have run into an issue where my JavaScript algorithm is wrong and I can't find out what is causing the issue. The issue is: the date does not matter, and the user can input any date below `2020-01-01` from `maxlength` from the form (JavaScript does not work)

```
function checkForm() {
  var answ = validateDate(document.getElementById("doa").value);
  if (answ == false) {
    return false;
  }
  return true;
}

function validateDate(doa) {
  var d = new Date(doa);
  var n = new Date();
  if (d <= n) {
    alert("Date cannot be before today");
    return false;
  }
  return true;
}
```

My Form:

```
<form action="advertResult.html" onsubmit="return checkForm()">
  <label class="formText">First Name:</label>
  <input type="text" id="firstName" name="firstname" placeholder="" required>

  <label class="formText">Last Name:</label>
  <input type="text" id="lastName" name="lastname" placeholder="" required>

  <label for="commission" class="formText">Type of Commission</label>
  <select id="commission" name="commission" required>
    <option value="drawing">Art</option>
    <option value="video">Video</option>
  </select>

  <label for="doa" class="formText">Select a date for discussion</label>
  <input type="date" name="date" id="doa" max="2020-01-01" required>

  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

Comment: what exactly is wrong - some error message, or form is (not) submitted when it should (not) be, or something else? please be as specific as possible

Comment: Noted, thanks for the heads up! I edited the question

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Compare two dates with JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/492994/compare-two-dates-with-javascript)

Comment: do you include the JS code by a `<script>` tag? if using other method, then `checkForm` might be a local function and the global one referenced from HTML will be undefined... you could do `window.checkForm = function() {...`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the HTML code refers to the global function `checkForm`, while the JS code can be defined in a variety of ways

unless it is included by an old-schoold `<script>` tag (either directly in HTML or using `src` attribute), then it is possible that the way how JS is included (such as using webpack) might convert the functions to local functions, and no global `checkForm` will be defined

in that case, you can define a global function (http://jsfiddle.net/w1m6c7v0/7/):

```
window.checkForm = function() {
  ...
```

or even better, add the event listener in JS (http://jsfiddle.net/w1m6c7v0/6/, though use an `id` attribute if you have more than 1 form):

```
document.querySelector('form').onsubmit = checkForm
function checkForm() {
  ...
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply! The javascript code is indeed in another file, however, I currently have issues trying to follow your method as I am slightly confused on how I should write the javascript code, is it supposed to be `window.checkForm = function(){
  var answ = validateDate(document.getElementById("doa").value);
  if(answ == false)
  {
    return false;
  }
return true;
}`

Comment: sure, that is the 1st option I suggested... though feel free to use `window.checkForm = function(){ return validateDate(document.getElementById("doa").value); }` combining advice from multiple answers

Comment: Hmm, I do not think the linking of the files are the issue now, I just tried to use your suggestions, and it still didn't work. I also then tried to use '<script></script' tag in the form.html file, but it still does not work, so I do not think that the issue is with the linking and calling of the JS Code

Comment: works perfectly fine for me in http://jsfiddle.net/w1m6c7v0/7/ - you talk about "didn't work" without being specific what exactly is actually happening vs what you expect to happen...

Comment: sorry for not clarifying, when I stated that it "did not work", I meant that the function wasn't running properly, e.g when I put in 04-03-1990 for the form, the function was supposed to alert the user that they should not put in a date that is earlier than today

Comment: how to you `put` it for the form? do you use the date selector? if not, then the manual value might need to be in the `yyyy-mm-dd` format otherwise `new Date('04-03-1990')` is Invalid Date

Comment: I used '<input type="date">' which gave me the format of mm/dd/yyyy by default in the form

Comment: the thing displayed on screen is not the input's value - for Chrome see [Quick FAQs on input\[type=date\]](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2012/08/Quick-FAQs-on-input-type-date-in-Google-Chrome) (it is similar in Firefox, no idea about other browsers) => how did you `put` it into the form? if by selecting a value from the date picker then I do not know what's wrong, but if you typed it manually then you typed it in the wrong format and it's an Invalid Date

Comment: Sorry! I just found the issue, it was with the <script> tag. The script tag was <script src="../script.js">. I removed src and placed it with a embedded js <script></script> tag and it works.

Answer (score 1):

update your code to do the date check

```
function checkForm() {
  return validateDate(document.getElementById("doa").value);
}

function validateDate(doa) {
  var d = new Date(doa);
  var n = new Date();
  return (d.getFullYear() >= n.getFullYear()) &&
    (d.getMonth() >= n.getMonth()) &&
    (d.getDate() >= n.getDate());
}
```

Comment: Date objects can be compared by `<=` just fine. good idea simplifying `checkForm` but it's equal to the original code so not fixing any problem that could be there...

Answer (score 1):

You can make use of the moment.js library : https://momentjs.com/

```
if(moment(doa)).isBefore())
  return false;
return true;
```

If nothing is passed to moment#isBefore, it will default to the current time.

Answer (score 0):

I tried the code and it looks good to me, maybe you are mistaking the format of the date which is `MM/DD/YYYY` , if I increase the DD it takes the user to `advertResult.html?firstname=xxfirstnamexx&lastname=xxlastnamenamexx&commission=drawing&date=2018-07-22` meaning it works fine.

[image]

Comment: the format of the JS `inputElement.value` is always a string `yyyy-mm-dd` in both Chrome and Firefox, they are not so cruel as to put the random user-locale format displayed on page as the actual value...